# Python: How can I get lower 95% confidence interval using Kaplan-Meier estimate for survival curve estimate

Tags: python, survival-analysis

Looks like we can use `Surv` and `survfit` function in R to get 95% lower bound confidence interval by using
`surv.fit <- survfit(...)`  and get the 95% CI using
`summary(surv.fit)`

On Python, I tried something like `kmf = KaplanMeierFitter()` and `kmf.fit(T, event_observed=C)`
Is there a way to get 95% lower bound CI on Python like R did?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`kmf.confidence_interval_`](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fitters/univariate/KaplanMeierFitter.html?highlight=kmf.confidence_interval_#lifelines.fitters.kaplan_meier_fitter.KaplanMeierFitter.confidence_interval_).